# What is the best way to connect UART to USB? (need HID compatability)

Tags: usb, uart, hid

I was wondering what would be the best method to add USB connectivity to one of my designs.  I have an Atmel ATMega328P which will be sending HID reports to my computer, but I need a bridge to go from UART to USB.

FTDI makes such a bridge, however it seems that these don't support the HID protocol.  Is there any other way to go from UART to USB and have my device show up as an HID device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried V-USB library? It's a fantastic library for AVR microcontrollers, also supports HID protocol.

Here's a link:
http://www.obdev.at/products/vusb/index.html

Comment: No I haven't actually.  I've been reading a little about it now, but just to be clear, I can simply add USB capability to my existing AVR microcontroller? If so that's great!

Comment: Yes, any AVR have sufficient Flash.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out SiLabs CP2110: http://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/TechnicalDocs/CP2110.pdf (USB HID <-> UART bridge)

Comment: In addition to SiLabs' CP2110, [FTDI's FT260](http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/ICs/FT260.html) might be interesting...

Comment: I hope he finished his project by now ;-)